# iOS - Distribution for Business and Education

Tags: ios, app-store, software-distribution

I've an custom app. Last 26th june , it has approved.

But on 28th june, mistakenly I've selected "Available on the App Store and for volume purchasing on Apple Business Manager and Apple School Manager" this option from pricing and availability and saved that.

After this "Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager" - this option has disabled.
My organization id is also not viewable.

[image: business]

But my app's status is still "Ready for sale".

I'm in very much fear. I'm very new in app distribution.
This was my first app.

Please tell me - what'll I do now?
Please help...

Comment: What happens if you select the first option and save that ?

Comment: @radioaktiv don't know. I'm in fear to select the first option...

Comment: Try that. You can always revert it. Also what is it you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: You need to ensure you have completed all of the requirements for paid app distribution for this option to become available, even if the app itself is free. This includes agreeing to the paid app distribution agreement, supplying required tax information and providing a bank account.  I saw something at WWDC that custom app distribution will be available for free distribution agreements but this does not seem to have gone into effect yet.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok Paulw11, but my app isn't free.

Comment: All the more reason why you must ensure that you have completed all of the tax and banking information.  However, even if you are selling the app to your customers you can make it free within AppStore connect and arrange for your customers to pay you outside the app store.  This is permitted with custom apps and saves you the 30% that Apple normally takes.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes , I've completed all things from tax and agreement section. Before my mistake , the 3rd point under "Distribution for Business and Education" - was visible. But it disabled after my mistake. But in business manager , app is showing perfectly. I'm tension for my next upgrade. as for my wrong selection.

Comment: @Paulw11 In my app, after launching - I saw top bar and text color has changed. it don't look similar with TestFlight version also. are there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Nothing to do with the distribution method.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, does the present selected distributed method will create problem to my next version?

Answer (score 0):

*The purpose to post the answer of this issue is to help - the people if anybody did similar mistake like mine.*

```
After uploading an new version - this issue is solved.
```